# Insert values of one table in a database to another table in another database

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I would like to take some data from a table from DB1 and insert some of that data to a table in DB2.

How would one proceed to do this?

This is what I've got so far:

```
CREATE VIEW old_study AS
SELECT *
FROM dblink('dbname=mydb', 'select name,begins,ends from study')
AS t1(name varchar(50), register_start date, register_end date);
/*old_study now contains the data I wanna transfer*/

INSERT INTO studies VALUES (nextval('studiesSequence'),name, '',3, 0, register_start, register_end)
SELECT name, register_start, register_end from old_study;
```

This is how my table in DB2 looks:

```
CREATE TABLE studies(
    id int8 PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name_string VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255),
    field int8 REFERENCES options_table(id) NOT NULL,
    is_active INTEGER NOT NULL,
    register_start DATE NOT NULL,
    register_end DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: In SQL world iterating is the worst possible scenario. You think in `ROW-by-ROW` manner. You need to switch to `SET BASED` approach.

Comment: check my updated asnwer

Comment: Does `INSERT INTO studies VALUES (nextval('studiesSequence'),name, '','Test', 0, register_start, register_end)
SELECT name, register_start, register_end from old_study;` successfully running without errors ??

Comment: No, it gives ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Comment: Yes because column specified in  `VALUES (nextval('studiesSequence'),name, '','Test', 0, register_start, register_end)`(_7 columns_) is **not** equal to  `SELECT name, register_start, register_end from old_study;`(_3 Columns_)

Comment: Revamp your question with exact thing that you're trying to achieve

Comment: You can do it like this http://hastebin.com/makeqolepu.sql

Comment: But I don't understand why you've specified this `nextval('studiesSequence'),name, '','Test', 0,`

Comment: Please check my revamped question. This time i've bene more specific i think.

Comment: You want get get entire table from one DB to another or what??

Comment: No, not the entire table, but some rows of one table (as specified - name, begins,ends). But I want additional data in addition to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO studies
(
    id
    ,name_string
    ,description
    ,field
    ,is_active
    ,register_start
    ,register_end
    )

SELECT nextval('studiesSequence')
    ,NAME
    ,''
    ,3
    ,0
    ,register_start
    ,register_end
FROM dblink('dbname=mydb', 'select name,begins,ends from study') 
     AS t1(NAME VARCHAR(50), register_start DATE, register_end DATE);
```

You can directly insert values that retured by `dblink()`(*that means no need to create a view*)

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 7: SELECT name, register_start, register_end from cte;
        ^

Comment: You'd have to remove the `VALUES` keyword, though.

Answer (score 3):

You should include the column names in both the `insert` and `select`:

```
insert into vip_employees(name, age, occupation)
    select name, age, occupation
    from employees;
```

However, your data structure is suspect.  Either you should use a flag in `employees` to identify the "VIP employees".  *Or* you should have a primary key in `employees` and use this primary key in `vip_employees` to refer to `employees`.  Copying over the data fields is rarely the right thing to do, especially for columns such as age which are going to change over time.  Speaking of that, you normally derive age from the date of birth, rather than storing it directly in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Loop and cursor are weapons of last resort. Try to avoid them. You probably want `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO x(x, y, z)
SELECT x, y, z
FROM t;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/039b9/1/1)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

```
INSERT INTO vip_employees(name, age, occupation) -- your column list may vary
SELECT name, age, occupation
FROM employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. You cannot have *both*, a values clause for constant values *and* a select clause for a query in your INSERT statement.

You'd have to select constant values in your query:

```
insert into studies 
(
  id,
  name_string,
  description,
  field,
  is_active,
  register_start,
  register_end
)
select
  studiesSequence.nextval,
  name, 
  'Test', 
  null,
  0,
  register_start, 
  register_end
from old_study;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me!
Althought you have to remove 'date' from register_start and register_end and change it to nextVal('studiesSequence')

Comment: Yeah, right. Copy & paste. I'll remove them. Thanks.